# Remove the year and month in blogger url

Tags: php, blogs, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

can i know how to remove date part from a blogger post

for ex check the below url: http://w2t-minit.blogspot.in/2015/03/photoshop-effects-part-2.html but i want that to be like below url http://w2t-minit.blogspot.in/photoshop-effects-part-2.html

i dont want the date part “2015/03” to be posted can you help me how to remove that ??

thanks

Comment: You have to do that with the .htaccess file on your server...

Comment: Or you simply don't save it in such a directory

Comment: Is it possible? is there any code changes or through admin change anything can be done to remove the date?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's impossible on Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

Split the absolute url, and extract the parts with REGEXP :

```
$url = parse_url('http://w2t-minit.blogspot.in/2015/03/photoshop-effects-part-2.html');
preg_match('#\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/(?P<url>.*)#', $url['path'], $matches);
```

`$matches['url']` will contain `photoshop-effects-part-2.html` . then re-assemble a full url :

```
$dateless = $url['scheme'] .'://'. $url['host'] .'/'.$matches['url'];
```

EDIT : I think I have misunderstood the question here.
I though is was tagged PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Sure narendra,

Replace:

```
span#metaDetail span#datePosted {
float: left;
margin-left: 30px;
height: 32px;
line-height: 32px;
}
```

with:

```
span#metaDetail span#datePosted {
display: none;
}
```